# Execute function in other php file

Tags: php, function, exec, shell-exec

I have a custom php unit that runs through a cronjob daily. I use this unit to make it easier to create new scheduled jobs. I use them to build my XMLTV guide.

I wrote a function `create_guide ($id)` which uses the id to find the configuration for the guide from the database. I use these configurations so i can have multiple guides made by one script.

Now i can use the `shell_exec()` and `exec()` to run scripts, but how can i use `exec()` to run the function `create_guide($id)` and pass the id? I have used CURL to execute scripts before, but there should be a nicer/better way to run these scripts wihout CURL?

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: maybe post the codes, so we can understand what you want

Comment: There's just one php script that runs on the cronjob, and that script includes some other php scripts already to make them run. This way i only need one script in the cronjob and keeps things easier to replace/edit.

What i want to do now, run a script that checks for the id's - read tv guides - that i want to make, and run the script that contains the function to create the guide with the id as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need to include the PHP file that contains the `create_guide($id)` function in it.  If this file is just a file that contains a bunch of functions or a class then this should work.

Like so:

cronjob.php

```
<?php

require 'path/to/create_guide.php';

//rest of cron job code.

$data = create_guide($id);

?>
```